# Hard delete a thread in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a large delete statement that I erroneously ran. I killed the thread that was running it...or so I thought. Now everything that targets that table with an update receives a deadlock.

Running `show engine innodb status;` produces the section that says:

```
ROLLING BACK 843518 lock struct(s), heap size 177184976, 19945380 row lock(s), undo log entries 864654
MySQL thread id 5267415, OS thread handle 47273603569408, query id 906734691 10.194.1.122 bq_connector query end
```

But then when I try and do `CALL mysql.rds_kill(5267415);` to kill the thread it doesn't actually 'do anything' -- that query/output just stays there. Why does this occur and is there a way to just hard-kill it?

Just looking at the output over time it seems like this is dropping:

> undo log entries 864654

So maybe when that gets to zero it will stop? **Update**: <-- Yes, when the log entries got to zero it killed the thread. What would happen if it just killed immediately and didn't do all the log entry un-dos?

Comment: Bad things.  The undo log is critical to Mysql's transaction processing.  It must be kept consistent.

Comment: *What would happen if it just killed immediately and didn't do all the log entry un-dos?* This will destroy your data consistency with high probability, and even may destroy your data at all. If a thread kill was requested then its current transaction is rollbacked unconditionally (exclusion - LOAD DATA), and you must wait until this process finished - without alternative.